# How to get the information from each CheckBox in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox, gettext

I am doing a small program about calculate the money in a shopping list.
I have a problem in tell the exact CheckBox I choose.
The program is followed:

My layout:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mne4u3va94svx8y/%E6%93%B7%E5%8F%96.JPG?dl=0

My "activity_main.xml"

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose the ingredients that you need" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_milk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Milk 80 $        " />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_rice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rice 240 $" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_milk"
                android:layout_width="122dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/milk" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_rice"
                android:layout_width="106dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:src="@drawable/rice" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_sausage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sausage 50 $" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_chicken"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chicken 350 $" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_sausage"
                android:layout_width="87dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sausage" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_chicken"
                android:layout_width="162dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.27"
                android:src="@drawable/chicken" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_rice_ball"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rice Ball 50 $" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_fish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fish 250 $" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_rice_ball"
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rice_ball" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_fish"
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/fish" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_buy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="buy"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Milk"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/milk"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Rice"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rice"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Sausage"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sausage"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Chicken"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/chicken"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Rice_Ball"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rice_ball"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_Fish"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fish"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroresult"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/show_result"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Result"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity_market.java

```js
package com.example.market_shop_3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity_market extends Activity 
 implements OnCheckedChangeListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_market);
        //program start here
        int[] id={R.id.check_milk, R.id.check_rice,R.id.check_sausage,R.id.check_chicken
          ,R.id.check_rice_ball,R.id.check_fish};
      for(int i:id) //loop for importand recoder listener
      {
       ((CheckBox)findViewById(i)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
      }
          
        
    }
    

    
    public void buy(View v)
    {
     String show_buy="";
    // String total_prices="";
     String test="";
     int count=0;
     
     
     CheckBox check;
     int[] id={R.id.check_milk, R.id.check_rice,R.id.check_sausage,R.id.check_chicken
          ,R.id.check_rice_ball,R.id.check_fish};
     for(int i:id)
     {
      check=(CheckBox)findViewById(i);
      if(check.isChecked())
      {
       show_buy+="\n"+check.getText();
       
       
       if (check.getText()=="milk 80 $" )
        count = count +80;
       else if (check.getText()=="Rice 240 $")
        count = count +240;
       else if (check.getText()=="Sausage 50 $")
        count = count +50;
       else if (check.getText()=="Chicken 350 $")
        count = count +350;
       else if (check.getText()=="Rice Ball 50 $")
        count = count +50;
       else if (check.getText()=="Fish 250 $")
        count = count +250;
        
      }
     }
     int total = count;
     
     if(show_buy.length()>0)
     {
      show_buy ="Your shopping list: "+show_buy +"\n"+"Total expenses: "+ total;
     // total_prices="Total expenses ($): "+ ;
     }
     else
      show_buy="Please pick the ingredients that you need.";
    TextView show_result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_result);
    show_result.setText(show_buy);
    }

    //設ArrayList儲存已選項目的集合物件
    ArrayList<CompoundButton> selected = new ArrayList<CompoundButton>();
    
 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton id, boolean isChecked)
 {   
  if (isChecked==true)   //若項目被選取
   selected.add(id);  //加到集合中
  else                   //若項目被取消
   selected.remove(id); //自集合中移除
  
  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int visible;
  if(isChecked){ //CHECKED
   visible=View.VISIBLE; //SET PICTURE IS VISIBLE
   }
  else{   //CANCEL CHECKED
   visible=View.GONE; //SET PICTURE IS NOT VISIBLE
  }
  switch (id.getId()){
  case R.id.check_milk:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Milk).setVisibility(visible);
   break;
  case R.id.check_rice:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Rice).setVisibility(visible);
   break;
  case R.id.check_sausage:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Sausage).setVisibility(visible);
   break;
  case R.id.check_chicken:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Chicken).setVisibility(visible);
   break;
  case R.id.check_rice_ball:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Rice_Ball).setVisibility(visible);
   break;
  case R.id.check_fish:
   findViewById(R.id.image_Fish).setVisibility(visible); 
   break;
  }
  
  
 }
}
```

In java part,

I am not how to tell the CheckBox I chose, I used the if-elseif condition (check.getText()=="milk 80 $" ;else if (check.getText()=="Rice 240 $")....) 
to judge how much money I should add for the total expense

I set a "int" called "count" to accumulate my total expense, but it seems that didn't work.

Failure result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj329jg0sj0ypd/1.JPG?dl=0

The "Total expense: 0" should be "Total expense: 670".

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2D array for ID-PRICE of each checkbox (shopping item)

```
int[] id_price={
{R.id.check_milk,80}, 
{R.id.check_rice,240},
{R.id.check_sausage,50},
{R.id.check_chicken,350},
{R.id.check_rice_ball,50},
{R.id.check_fish}, 250};
```

on button click (to calculate all selected list)
or on each item (checkbox) checked or unchecked:

```
CheckBox check = null;
int total = 0;
for(int i=0;i<id_price.length;i++){
    check=(CheckBox)findViewById(id_price[i][0]);
    if(check.isChecked()){
        total += id_price[i][1];//add item price to total
    }else{
        total -= id_price[i][1];//subtract item price from total
    }
}//for all check boxes
//now you have total ready for your next step ...
```

this way no need for `IF statement`